# Label smoothing in caffe with prototxt without data regeneration

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, protocol-buffers, caffe

I've got a huge data set in LMDB (40Gb) that I use for training a binary classifier with caffe.

Data layer in Caffe contains integer labels.

Are there any ready layers that could transform them into floats with adding some random jitter, so I could apply label smoothing technique, as described in 7.5.1 [here](http://www.deeplearningbook.org/contents/regularization.html)

I have seen examples with HDF5, but they require regenerating data set, and I would like to avoid it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`DummyData`](http://caffe.help/manual/layers/dummydata.html) layer to generate the random noise you wish to add to the labels. Once you have the noise, use [`Eltwise`](http://caffe.help/manual/layers/eltwise.html) layer to sum them up:

```
layer {
  name: "noise"
  type: "DummyData"
  top: "noise"
  dummy_data_param {
    shape { dim: 10 dim: 1 dim: 1 dim: 1 } # assuming batch size = 10
    data_filler { type: "uniform" min: -0.1 max: 0.1 } # noise ~U(-0.1, 0.1) 
  }
}
layer {
  name: "label_noise"
  type: "Eltwise"
  bottom: "label"  # the input integer labels
  bottom: "noise"
  top: "label_noise"
  eltwise_param { operation: SUM }
}
```